# Changing a vote on an answer even though there has been no edit

Tags: discussion, voting

A year ago, I upvoted an answer to a question.  Today, I stumbled across the same answer and.  Comments made since my vote correctly pointed out flaws in the answer that I had overlooked.  I should not have voted it up.

I'm not allowed to change my vote because it's old and because the answer hasn't been edited since.  I understand the intent of this rule, but I question whether the comments that were added after my answer should be taken into account.

Would it be feasible to change the restriction so that the addition of comments is considered the same as an edit?  What would the negative consequences be?

If I cared strongly enough, I suppose could edit the answer myself, and then remove my upvote, but that seems rather egregious behavior, and I don't have the domain knowledge to actually correct the answer.  On the other hand, I don't like the idea that my upvote might mislead the next hapless SO user who happens upon the answer.

(I'm intentionally not linking to the answer, because I don't believe the details are relevant to whether the restriction should be revised.)

Comment: Well, I do share the same feeling with you, however it makes me think hard every time before I cast a vote to a question, either up or down. It makes you more responsible about your vote. But other than that, I can't see other negative consequences.

Comment: @Neeku:  The negative consequences are (1) the vote can be misleading as I explained, and (2) there's a perverse incentive for someone to edit the question just so that they could revise their vote.  Why shouldn't a good comment be considered as relevant as an edit to the actual answer?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, and I'm surprised that no one has any clue on this so far. :-/